# Security in Android - Google app engine system

Tags: java, android, python, google-app-engine, pycrypto

So i have an android app, and a google app engine server written in python.
The android app needs to send some **sensible** information to the server, and the way I do that is by doing an http post.

Now i have been thinking about encrypting the data in android before sending it, and decrypting it once it is on the gae server.

This is how i encrypt and decrypt in java :

```
private static final String ALGO = "AES";



public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
     //   String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);

        byte[] decoded = Base64.encodeBase64(encVal);

        return (new String(decoded, "UTF-8") + "\n");
    }

public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue =Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);

        return decryptedValue;

    }

    private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(Constant.keyValue, ALGO);
        return key;
    }
```

And this is how i try to decrypt on the server (i don't know yet how to do the encryption..maybe you guys can help with that too)

```
def decrypt(value):
    key = b'1234567891234567'

    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    msg = cipher.decrypt(value)

    return msg
```

As i looked in the logs, the string test that i get is : `xVF79DzOplxBTMCwAx+hoeDJhyhifPZEoACQJcFhrXA=` and because it is not a multiple of 16 (idk why, i guess this is because of the java encryption) i get the error

ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in lenght

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you not using ssl (aka https)? That should provide all the encryption needed to transport data securely and privately between the phone and App Engine.

Comment: @Fh. any tutorial/resource where i would see how to do that ? I am kind of a newby :)

Comment: longer answer added as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This string "xVF79DzOplxBTMCwAx+hoeDJhyhifPZEoACQJcFhrXA=" is a base64-encoded value.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Base64 encoding is widely used lots of applications, it's a good way to encode binary data into text.  If you're looking at a long encoded value, the "=" at the end can be a good indicator of base64 encoding.

In your python code you probably need to base64 decode the data before handing it to the decryption function.

I have two recommendations:

1. If crypto isn't a comfort zone for you, consult with someone who is good in this area for your project.
2. Be aware that embedding a symmetric encryption key in an Android app that you distribute is a bad idea.  Anyone that can get a copy of your app can extract that key and use it to decrypt or spoof your messages.

Comment: @Teshte no.  Plenty of discussions on here about this.  Simple rule.  If it really needs to be secure, don't put it on a phone.

Comment: One option would be to push a unique symmetric key down to the app during user setup.  You would need to keep track of those keys on the server side so you know which key belongs to which user.  On the app side you should look at the Android docs for the right storage location for app secrets.

Comment: @u2702 so the idea with my app is that i wanted to encrypt the data to a minimum, so that if the user uses a public wifi network that is scaned, his name and telephone not to appear to that person. For him to get them (from what i understand from you), he would need to get my apk (and from there on the source code and that key that i use). But if the person uses the app from his mobile network, then there is no risk,unless the CIA wants that message :).Thanks for the help. For version 1 of my app i will probably leave this as it is, and the next version will have some way of increased security

Answer (score 2):

Why are you not using ssl (aka https)? That should provide all the encryption needed to transport data securely and privately between the phone and App Engine.

The basics of it: Instead of sending data to http://yourapp.appspot.com/, send it to https://yourapp.appspot.com/.

For a complete secure and authenticated channel between App Engine and Android, you can use Google Cloud Endpoints. It will even generate the Android side code to call it.

Java:

- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/
- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android

Python:

- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/
- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android

For a longer show and tell, check the IO 13 talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5u_Owtbfew

Comment: thanks a lot...so can this still work if i have python server ?

Comment: I agree with this suggestion, but be aware of the ramifications on GAE.  If I remember correctly there are cost issues associated with having HTTPS on your own domain (not sure what the current status is):
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl

Comment: Tom - Notice that link goes to 'custom domains' support. For vanilla *.appspot.com domains, it's free (within quota limitations). https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#https

Comment: @Fh. so if i want to have a custom domain (myapp.com), I need to pay for HTTPS (and implicitly for clound endpoints on a custom domain)? `You must have an App Engine application with billing enabled that has cleared at least one billing charge; use this application when enabling SSL. `   If the answer is yes, then i guess i will pass endpoints, until my app will have some success, and i will have a reason to invest more money into it :).  Correct me if i am wrong :)

Comment: @Fh. and one more question, when i post to the server, i also send a key (as posted data), and i verify that key on the server side. What i basically do is to verify that the post is made by my android app, and not somebody else that knows what to post, and where to post it...But if somebody can see my source code, they can see both the key, and the link where to post...and he can post spam for example...Would endpoints help here?

Comment: Most likely you won't need a custom domain for an api, as no one will see the url anyway.

Comment: No need to include an unsafe discoverable key with android. The linked video explains why.